# How rerender cloned childs with new props after they are initially rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The idea is to make a form that will validate the inputs and put all the logic for validating inside the MyForm component. so the only thing that comes from the onsubmit call is a error object and a object with the form values.

i would also like to validate when the user clicks on submit and when the user touched a field with onBlur.
i would like to keep all the logic in MyForm

The problem is that i'm trying to figure out how to change the InputGroup props from MyForm component and display validation errors for example.
how can i change to props of the childs when the user clicks the submit button or a field is touched and call the handleBlur in InputGroup.

also tell me is this is a wrong approach

i managed to change the props of InputGroup from MyForm at runtime.
this will change the label of every child.

```
children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
  React.cloneElement(child, {
    label: 'foo'
  })
 )

 ...

 return (
    <form onSubmit={this.validate}>
       {children}
    </form>
 )
```

NewCustomerContainer:

```
class NewCustomerContainer extends Component {

    handleSubmit(errors, customer) {
        // if errors is empty do something with customer
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={shared.flexRow}>
                <div className={shared.flexColumn}>
                    <ColumnHeader
                        headerTitle="New Customer" />
                    <MyForm formHandler={this.handleSubmit}>

                        <InputGroup
                            type="text"
                            label="Customer Name"
                            placeholder="Customer Name"
                            name="customerName"
                            isRequired={true} />
                        <InputGroup
                            type="text"
                            label="Customer Number"
                            placeholder="Customer Number"
                            name="customerNumber" />
                        <InputGroup
                            type="text"
                            label="Customer Email"
                            placeholder="Customer Email"
                            name="customerEmail"
                            isRequired={true}
                            validateOption="email" />
                    </MyForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NewCustomerContainer
```

MyForm

```
    export class MyForm extends Component {

        validate(e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
              React.cloneElement(child, {
                label: 'foo'
              })
            )

            // handle validation login here
            // then call the parent function with the errors and values

            this.props.testForm(errors, values)
        }

        render() {
          const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
            React.cloneElement(child, {

            })
          )
          return (
            <form onSubmit={this.validate}>
                {children}
            </form>
          )
        }
    }
```

InputGroup:

```
export class InputGroup extends Component {

    handleBlur() {
       // handle blur here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={shared.formGroup}>
                <label className={shared.formLabel}>{this.props.label}</label>
                <input className={shared.formError} type={this.props.type} name={this.props.name} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
                <span className={shared.formError}>{this.props.foo}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

i'm very new to React and i know i can use redux-form or a other plugin, but i want to challenge myself and understand the concept how children works. there are plenty of examples out there but they do not answer my questions

thanks in advance.